# Problem with excluding namespace from XmlWriter.WriteStartElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, syndication

I have a little problem that perhaps you can help me with.

I try to use the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) to write an XML-tag that looks like this ([w3c feed recommendation](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html)):

```
<atom:link href="http://localhost" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

The problem is that I can't use the [WriteStartElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartelement.aspx)-method as I would want to (atom as a prefix and link as the element name), since this gives me a "*ArgumentException: Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace*".

**My code looks like this:**

```
public void WriteTo(XmlWriter writer, Feed feed)
{
    // RSS element
    writer.WriteStartElement("rss", "");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "atom", string.Empty, "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

    // Channel element
    writer.WriteStartElement("channel");

    // The link to the feed.
    writer.WriteStartElement("link", "atom");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("href", feed.FeedUrl.ToString());
    writer.WriteAttributeString("rel", "self");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "application/rss+xml");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    // Feed information
    writer.WriteElementString("title", feed.Title);
    writer.WriteElementString("description", feed.Description);
    writer.WriteElementString("link", feed.Link.ToString());

    // Iterate through all items.
    foreach (FeedItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("item");
        writer.WriteElementString("title", item.Title);
        writer.WriteElementString("link", item.Link.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("description", item.Description);
        writer.WriteElementString("guid", item.Guid);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    // Channel element end
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    // RSS element end
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

I assume that my problem is trivial and can easily be solved, but how?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is solved. Check Jon Skeets answer for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the appropriate namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`)?

You could write the namespace declaration earlier, in which case you only need the `WriteStartElement` overload which takes the element name and namespace - I *think* the prefix is then used automatically.

Comment: The appropriate namespace is already included. The result I get from you suggestion is 

<link href="http://localhost:56011/Home/Feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" xmlns="atom" />

I've updated the example above with the result I get. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I noticed that the validator at https://validator.w3.org/feed/ wasn't happy with the output as xmln="atom" thus I changed the WriteStartElement to writer.WriteStartElement("atom", "link", null); and got the desired output <atom:link href="localhost:5001/blog/feed/rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />